# Trying to add a custom event to Speech Synthesis object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, speech-synthesis

I am trying to add a custom event to a Speech Synthesis object in Javascript.

```
let msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
msg.voiceURI = 'native';
msg.volume = 1;
msg.rate = .7;
msg.pitch = 1;
msg.text = '恭喜发财';
msg.lang = 'zh-CN';

var event = new Event('build');
msg.addEventListener('build', function (e) { console.log("custom event success"); }, false);
msg.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Nothing happens when I run this code - and I'm not sure if I am going in the right direction.

I am trying to create a more granular event than the "onboundary" event - which just measures a word or sentence ending and gives the character index.

I want to measure each and every character ending in the Speech Synthesis API - this may in fact not be the right way to do this - but my understanding of the Javascript event system isn't complete.

How would I add a custom event that fires on every change of the charIndex value of Speech Synthesis?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesisEvent/charIndex

I can get this value in onboundary, but it just doesn't provide the granularity I need.

Comment: you're missing a `)` after `console.log("custom event success"`

Comment: Oh thank you, typo - that's what I get for just trying to write something in the JS console. So now I can get it to fire on .dispatchEvent(), but how do I fire it on charIndex change?